# Which clustering technique to use for 1D data with 2 Gaussian distributions without training data?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have 1D data which is likely to be 2 Gaussian distributions overlapped. I do not have training data but I know one should be slightly high contributed from few points and another is very broad with almost of data. Are there some clustering techniques possible to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian mixture modeling optimizes the fit of Gaudeians to your data.